# get (multi)return value from a std::tuple function QtConcurrentRun

Tags: c++, qt, tuples

Hi I have a class for generate MD5 of some file in Qt, (I use tuple to return multiple value from it), I want to run it on other thread because its possible that generate all file MD5s takes some time and its freeze gui
I decide to use **QtConcurrentRun** for run it on other Thread, but so far I don't have any Idea about How can I get all tuple return values
here is my code

**HashGen.h**

```cpp
#pragma once

#include "stdafx.h"

class HashGen : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    HashGen(QObject *parent = nullptr);

private:
    QString Md5_gen(QString const& fname);

public slots:
    std::tuple<int, int, int> check_sequential();
};
```

**HashGen.cpp**

```cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "HashGen.h"

HashGen::HashGen(QObject *parent)
    : QObject(parent)
{
}

QString HashGen::Md5_gen(QString const& fname)
{
    //Generate MD5 of giving file name
}

std::tuple<int, int, int> HashGen::check_sequential() {
    QString file1[2] = { "8c0b1e6492078bdc113faae3d34fa5c5", "" }; // empty "" fill with other MD5 hash later
    QString file2[4] = { "0547f42982dd9edb7b47931d00efff15", "", "", "" };
    QString file3[2] = { "57f08e690e2655749291b2da4be8b021", "" };

    QString file1_H = Md5_gen("/proj/file.zip");
    QString file2_H = Md5_gen("/proj/file2.zip");
    QString file3_H = Md5_gen("/proj/file3.zip");

    int file1_status = 0;
    int file2_status = 0;
    int file3_status = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        if (file1[i] != "nofile")
        {
            if (file1[i] == file1_H)
            {
                file1_status = i;
                break;
            }
            else { file1_status = 422; } // Just a random number mean file doesn't match any MD5
        }
        else
        {
            file1_status = 404; // Just a random number mean file doesn't exist
            break;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        if (file2[i] != "nofile")
        {
            if (file2[i] == file2_H)
            {
                file2_status = i;
                break;
            }
            else { file2_status = 422; }
        }
        else
        { 
            file2_status = 404;
            break; 
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        if (file3[i] != "nofile")
        {
            if (file3[i] == file3_H)
            {
                file3_status = i;
                break;
            }
            else { file3_status = 422; }
        }
        else
        {
            file3_status = 404;
            break;
        }
    }

    return { file1_status, file2_status, file3_status}; // Return all file status
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```cpp
void mainwindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QFuture<std::tuple<int, int, int>> Hash = QtConcurrent::run(Gen, &HashGen::check_sequential);
    QFutureWatcher<std::tuple<int, int, int>>* watcher = new QFutureWatcher<std::tuple<int, int, int>>;
    connect(watcher, &QFutureWatcher<std::tuple<int, int, int>>::finished, this, &MafiaDEDLFox::AfterHash);
    watcher->setFuture(Hash);
}
```

one other problem is I need to use QFuturewatcher to watch for QFuture, but I don't know where is best place to declare it (so its don't remove when function go out of scope)
sorry if I cant explain my problem right, but I hope someone help me, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of getting value from `QFutureWatcher` you can send it via signal. And we can create a disposable `QFutureWatcher` that delete itself when the job done.

```
class HashGen : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    HashGen(QObject *parent = nullptr);

private:
    QString Md5_gen(QString const& fname);

public slots:
    std::tuple<int, int, int> check_sequential() {
        ...

        // notify when completed
        emit check_sequential_completed(file1_status, file2_status, file3_status);
        return { file1_status, file2_status, file3_status}; // Return all file status
    }
    
    void async_check_sequential() {
        // create future watcher as child
        auto futureWatcher = new QFutureWatcher<void>(this);
        // kill yourself when you done
        connect(futureWatcher, &QFutureWatcher<void>::finished, futureWatcher, &QObject::deleteLater);
        // Wait for finish of computation when HashGen about to die
        connect(this, &QObject::destroyed, [futureWatcher](){ futureWatcher->waitForFinished(); });
        // start check sequential in another thread
        futureWatcher.setFuture(QtConcurrent::run(this, &HashGen::check_sequential));
    }

signals:
    void check_sequential_completed(int, int, int);
};
```

Connect `check_sequential_completed` to slot where you need.

```
connect(Gen, &HashGen::check_sequential_completed, this, &MafiaDEDLFox::AfterHash);
```

You don't have to make future watcher disposable of course. If you find it inefficient to create new object every time, you can keep it as member of `HashGen`.

**Note:**
Instead of passing 3 int atguments, it is possible to send `std::tuple<int, int, int>`. You have to register meta type for queued connections which is a connection type used in interthread connections.

```
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(std::tuple<int, int, int>);
qRegisterMetaType<std::tuple<int, int, int>>();
```

**Edit1:**
`QFutureWatcher<std::tuple<int,int,int>>` replaced by `QFutureWatcher<void>`, no need store result in this solution.

**Edit2:**
Connection added that waits for asynchronous computation to finish, when `HashGen` object destroyed. So threads won't keep running on a dead object. But it will block the main thread for a while when `HashGen` destroyed. Actually that's the whole point of using `QFutureWatcher`, otherwise if you are sure there will be no asynchronous computation when destroying `HashGen` object, no need to use `QFutureWatcher`. Just `QtConcurrent::run` is suffice.

**Example Using Only QtConcurrent::run**

Following code snipped is from an actual working project.

```
class AddPrinterInvoker : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    AddPrinterInvoker(QObject* parent = nullptr);
    QStringList scanAddresses() {
       ...
       emit addressListReady(addressList);
       return addressList;
    }

public slots:
    void asyncScanAddresses() { QtConcurrent::run(this, &AddPrinterInvoker::scanAddresses); }

signals:
    void addressListReady(QStringList addressList);
}
```

Connections

```
connect(scanButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), m_invoker, SLOT(asyncScanAddresses()));

connect(m_invoker, SIGNAL(addressListReady(QStringList)), this, SLOT(updateAddressList(QStringList)));
```

Comment: thank you for great answer, so you saying there is no need to use tuple function to return multiple value, instead its better to use a signal and send all outputs to slot in GUI thread? just one question, so you think there is no need for `QFuture` and `QFutureWatcher`, just run the function with `QtConcurren`t and wait for signal to send data. right?

Comment: @file-tracer If you are sure there is no thread running when HashGen destroyed, then there is no need to use `QFutureWatcher`.Unlike `finished()` or `resultReadyAt()` signal, you can get result with custom signal in a single step. `QFutureWatcher`'s some features does not work with `QtConcurrent::run` such as `cancel()`, so I think it is more appealing option with other `QtConcurrent` functions.

Comment: thank you, one other thing, I want to run HashGen function from my main thread (gui) after a button pushed, but I dont know why i do what you said, but my program crash, debugger said its because `check_sequential_completed` signal... can you please add a example of running function in new thread from main thread and get output of it in main thread again? Im new in qt im be grateful if you can help me in this

Comment: @file-tracer I just added an example from one of my project and just tested it. It works fine. I don't why is your program crashes. Sorry.